# displaying a secondary child object in an array

Tags: html, angular

What I'm trying to do display some data returned from an API which is working perfectly, but the issue is there is a child object in an object which has to be displayed too and i'm finding difficulty in doing that.

DATA

```
[{"id":5,"referenceId":1189,"firstName":"Dan","lastName":"Daniels","orders":[{"id":109,"meals":[{"id":47,"name":"Fried Rice","description":"This is a  very sweet meal","image":"","mealType":"LUNCH","unitPrice":-20,"status":"ENABLED"}],"serveDate":"2019-07-11 00:00:00"}]}]
```

HTML

```
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let parent of todayOrder" class="table-row" #row>
              <td>
                {{parent.firstName}} {{parent.lastName}}
              </td>
              <td>
                <span *ngFor="let child of parent.orders.meals"> {{child.name}}. </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
```

The data I want to access is `meals` which is in `orders`.
I've tried `let child of parent.orders.meals` but its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're missing a step in your ngFors, as orders is an array and not an object:

```
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let parent of todayOrder" class="table-row" #row>
          <td>
            {{parent.firstName}} {{parent.lastName}}
          </td>
          <td>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let order of parent.orders">
              <span *ngFor="let child of orders.meals"> {{child.name}}. </span>
            </ng-container>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

or if you know you only want the first order ever:

```
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let parent of todayOrder" class="table-row" #row>
          <td>
            {{parent.firstName}} {{parent.lastName}}
          </td>
          <td>
            <span *ngFor="let child of parent.orders[0].meals"> {{child.name}}. </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```